# TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to load form. Details: Error thrown: [object Object] Text status: parsererror

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento-1.7, prestashop-1.6

I'm sorry to bring back this old subject but I'm facing an issue that even surprises me, my PrestaShop store is throwing this error when a user wants to log in.

*TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to load form. Details: Error thrown: [object Object] Text status: parsererror*

I tried almost everything, I disable the CCC in the admin of PrestaShop, it fixes the issue but mess up the CSS abundantly, then I tried to check the ajax function that deals with, it just keeps throwing the same error, I tried fixing the ajax function myself but the reduction doesn't work well, I disable the non native module but it still didn't work well.

Im out of solution here guys please I need help.